# Android Autoscrolling view without images

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, scroll, banner

I am currently trying to implement a banner-like view where given a list of strings, the view will cyclically show each string one after the other with a pause when they arrive in the center of the screen. An example of what I want to do is the following
[image: Sliding banner]

In HTML, this element is a swiper slide from swiperjs, however, Android has no native element that does this simply.

I have looked online for a couple of days now, testing various implementations using a custom RecyclerView, simple TextView with marquee (which doesn't have the pause I want to add) and have found that the majority of "solutions" revolve around either a RecyclerView, a ListView or a ViewPager with usually a TimerTask to handle the scrolling timing.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any implementation that works nor any indication as to which view is best to use.

All solutions implement an image and a dot selector showing which image from the list is shown on screen but I have absolutely no desire to have an image, I simply want a TextView with the same functionality. Before anyone asks, yes I have tried to simply replace the Images with a TextView but it simply doesn't work.

One important aspect to note is that since I am only trying to make some text scroll into view, I don't think ViewPager is an effective solution since I am not at all implementing some scrolling fragments. Here is a layout of how the screen elements are disposed (Note this is the MainActivity screen and I have a fragment host within it for all other fragments):

```
+-------------+-------------+
|             |   Toolbar   |
|             |-------------+
|             |    Banner   |
|             |-------------+
| Nav Drawer  |             |
|             |             |
|             |  Fragment   |
|             |             |
|             |             |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Any leads in the direction how to implement this functionality is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using LoopingViewPager like this.

Step 1: add dependancy in your app gradle

```
implementation 'com.asksira.android:loopingviewpager:1.1.2'
```

Step 2: add following code in your activity/fragment

```
    val sliderAdapter = SliderAdapter(this, arrayListOf("Your Text here","Your Text here","Your Text here"))

    val viewPager=findViewById<LoopingViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)

    viewPager.adapter = sliderAdapter
```

Step 3: Add LoopingViewPager view in your Activity/Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.asksira.loopingviewpager.LoopingViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:autoScroll="true"
        app:isInfinite="true"
        app:scrollInterval="3000"
        app:wrap_content="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 4: Create Adapter for LoopingViewPager

```
class SliderAdapter(context: Context, val itemList2: ArrayList<String>) :

LoopingPagerAdapter<String>(context, itemList2, true) {

override fun inflateView(viewType: Int, container: ViewGroup?, listPosition: Int): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.slider_layout, container, false)
}

override fun bindView(convertView: View?, listPosition: Int, viewType: Int) {

    var a = itemList2.get(listPosition)
    convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)?.text=a
}
}
```

Step 5: Create layout for an item

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you! Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly! Had to modify some elements of your answer such as nullable parameters but perfect solution. Thank you very much !